# Can't download Marketplace games to US Xbox in foreign country (non-US)

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, xbox-network

I have a Xbox 360 slim from the US and recently I bought FIFA 13 from the Marketplace in South America (Ecuador) and then I downloaded it. At 70% of the download completed, a notification shows up on the bottom that says "Can't Download FIFA 13". I tried again and the same thing happens. Is there any way to download FIFA 13 from the Marketplace in a foreign country?

Answer (score 2):

This could entirely be an issue with Xbox Live's Servers/your connection to them/your ISP and Data Caps (if any). [Check Here](http://support.xbox.com/es-EC/xbox-live-status) for current Xbox Status and unfortunately you'll need to contact [Xbox Support](http://support.xbox.com/es-EC/contact-us#1:0:7) for true diagnosis of the full issue.

## Steps I know they will make you do:

1. Unplug Router and Modem for 60 Seconds
2. Plug in Router and Modem
3. Retry download.

### Other Steps

1. Verify that you have ports listed [here](http://support.xbox.com/es-EC/xbox-live/connecting/network-ports-used-xbox-live) open and forwarded to your Xbox's IP ( Consult [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?client=tmpg&hl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fportforward.com%2Flangs%2Fdefault.htm&langpair=en|es) link for info on how to do this.)
2. [Clear your Xbox's Cache](http://support.xbox.com/es-EC/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/clear-system-cache)

After those the only other thing I can think of is do you have enough Hard Drive Space for your game?

Good Luck!

All links are to spanish/Ecuador links, If you want to view them in english please click the ones below:

- [Xbox Live Status](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status)
- [Xbox Support Contact](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us#1:0:7)
- [Xbox Live Ports](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/connecting/network-ports-used-xbox-live)
- [Port Forwarding Help (List of Routers)](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/)
- [Clear Xbox Cache](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/clear-system-cache)